# How to make a POST Request in Vue.js and Laravel 5.4

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, laravel-5.3

How can I remove this error and how can I retrieve the data that I have passed via POST Request in Vue.js

This is my `app.js`, focus only on the red box.

[image]

Added this code to enable csrf_token.

[image]

This is the `Route` that what I'm trying to get a response

[image]

This is my `Controller`

[image]

And this is the error what I have encountered.

[image]

I want to know what is missing or wrong in my codes. I need your help.

Comment: Greetings! Please refrain from [uploading code as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Instead, write it directly in the question and style it properly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive a `MethodNotAllowedException` because you defined a `GET` route but need a `POST` one.

Try to use

```
Route::post('page-send-message', 'MainController@send');
```

instead of

```
Route::get('page-send-message', 'MainController@send');
```

Anyway, using the axios library is recommended instead of a Vue post request. For more information look into the [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js) of laravel